# 403 forbidden error on new RatticDB server Debian 9

Tags: debian, apache2, http-status-code-403, apache2.4

Brand new server designed to run RatticDB, running Debian 9 (Stretch) on VMware. 
After setting up, everything appears to be working to start.

Running Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)

Internal domain name redirects to server, get the certificate error, and continue. Then get the 403 error, "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Permissions in /etc/apache2 are all owned by root, and read access for everyone.
Permissions in /opt/apps/RatticWeb are also the same.

One thing I find interesting is that there seems to be a mix of approval types.

From apache2.conf:

```
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share>
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    #<Directory /srv/>
    #       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #       AllowOverride None
    #       Require all granted
    #</Directory>
```

From apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

Alias /robots.txt /opt/apps/RatticWeb/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /opt/apps/RatticWeb/static/favicon.ico

AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /opt/apps/RatticWeb/static/styles/$1

Alias /media/ /opt/apps/RatticWeb/media/
Alias /static/ /opt/apps/RatticWeb/static/

<Directory /opt/apps/RatticWeb/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
#Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /opt/apps/RatticWeb/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
#Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/apps/RatticWeb/ratticweb/wsgi.py
WSGIPassAuthorization On

#WSGIDaemonProcess rattic processes=2 threads=25 home=/opt/apps/RatticWeb/ python-path=/opt/apps/RatticWeb display-na$
WSGIProcessGroup rattic


<Directory /opt/apps/RatticWeb/ratticweb>
  <Files wsgi.py>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
#    Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

Located in apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ServerName ratticdb.<domainname>.lan
    ServerAlias ratticdb
    Redirect permanent / https://ratticdb.<domainname>.lan/
```

I can't seem to locate where I am getting an issue that gives me the 403 error. When I make some changes based on others experiences (i.e.: Change "Order deny,allow" to "Require all granted"), I get a 500 internal error.

Any other recommendations on getting past this error and launching the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the **apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf** file.

The line: **WSGIDaemonProcess rattic processes=2 threads=25 home=/opt/apps/RatticWeb/ python-path=/opt/apps/RatticWeb display-na$** should have been **WSGIDaemonProcess rattic processes=2 threads=25 home=/opt/apps/RatticWeb/ python-path=/opt/apps/RatticWeb display-name=%{GROUP}**

This was caused by nano and the line being longer than the window.